# Trying to add line break after value is retrieved in for each loop in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

```
<div class="selected-items">          
    <template for:each={selectedOptions} for:item="selectedOption">
      <span class="selected-item" key={selectedOption}>        
        <span class="remove-item slds-float_left" style="font-size: 18px;" data-value={selectedOption} onclick={handleRemoveClick}>
         {selectedOption} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ×    <br> 
        </span>  <br>                   
      </span>     
    </template>
  </div>
```

My output is displayed in same line, see below image
br tag within template is not supported because the content within the template is rendered as a virtual DOM and does not support certain HTML tags including br tag

what is the alternative solution to include line break?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the element you are displaying instead of span did you tried simply putting it in a div

```
    <div class="selected-items">          
        <template for:each={selectedOptions} for:item="selectedOption">
          <divclass="selected-item" key={selectedOption}>        
            <div class="remove-item " style="font-size: 18px;" data-value={selectedOption} onclick={handleRemoveClick}>   
            {selectedOption} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
            </div>                  
          </div>     
        </template>
      </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately both suggestion doesn't work for me

Comment: did you remove slds-float_left.....

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` is an inline attribute. [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

`<div>` is a block attribute. [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)

Thus replacing all `<span>` with `<div>` should make the values display one below another.

```
<div class="selected-items">
    <template for:each={selectedOptions} for:item="selectedOption">
        <div class="selected-item" key={selectedOption}>
            <div class="remove-item" style="font-size: 18px;" data-value={selectedOption}>
                {selectedOption} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ×
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```